# Saving Date/Time to UserDefaults through didSet on @Published var (from TimePicker component of SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to save Checkin time preferences of a user (to send them notification reminders). So far I've been able to save a Bool and string to UserDefaults but I'm unable to figure out how to save the **time** preference. Here's my UserSettings class to store the preferences.

```
public class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    
    @Published var eveningCheckin: Bool {
        didSet{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(eveningCheckin, forKey: "eveningCheckin")
            print("Evening checkin toggle value in didSET to \(self.eveningCheckin)")
            
        }
    }
    
    @Published var eveningCheckinTime: Date {
        didSet{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(eveningCheckinTime, forKey: "eveningCheckinTime")
            print("Evening checkin didSet to \(self.eveningCheckinTime)")
        }
    }
    
    
    init() {

        self.eveningCheckin = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "eveningCheckin") as? Bool ?? false
        self.eveningCheckinTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "eveningCheckinTime") as? Date ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 64800)
        print("Evening checkin time init to \(self.eveningCheckinTime)")// --> To debug
        print("Evening checkin toggle value in init to \(self.eveningCheckin)")
    }
}
```

I want to set this Evening checkin time up with a Time picker that SwiftUI provides like this. Here are my Settings and Timepicker views.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsMain: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    @State private var showTimepickerEvening = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    //Evening checkins
                    Button(action: {
                        //Show  Evening time picker sheet
                        self.showTimepickerEvening.toggle()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(userSettings.eveningCheckinTime.hour12):\(userSettings.eveningCheckinTime.minute0x) \(userSettings.eveningCheckinTime.amPM.lowercased()) ")
                            Text("Change >")
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showTimepickerEvening) {
                        //Sheet view with the Timepicker
                        TimePickerView(pickedTime: self.$userSettings.eveningCheckinTime)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Preferences", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct TimePickerView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Binding var pickedTime: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Checkin time", selection: $pickedTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .labelsHidden()
            
            Button(action: {
                    //Dimiss. Should I actually update my UserDefaults here as well?
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        ColorManager.buttonGrey
                        Text("Save time")
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 64)
                }
            .padding(.all)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

**My problem is that the Time picker does setup the time into the @Published var BUT it get's reset with the init statement. It does not happen with the Bool value. Why??**

Here's the output from the print() statements above: Basically means that every time I'm trying to use the Datepicker to set the time -> didSet does choose the new time but init() resets it back to default.

> Evening checkin didSet to 1970-01-01 12:12:00 +0000
>
> Evening checkin time init to 1970-01-01 18:00:00 +0000
>
> Evening checkin toggle value in init to true
>
> Evening checkin didSet to 1970-01-01 12:13:00 +0000
>
> Evening checkin time init to 1970-01-01 18:00:00 +0000
>
> Evening checkin toggle value in init to true

Comment: How are you storing `UserSettings` on your view which contains the `DatePicker`? Please include the code for your view as well.

Comment: If you change your question my answer will not make any sense

Comment: Agreed Leo, My code had your answer in place. The bug in storing the time is still prevalent. Sorry about my mess up.

Comment: @AditGupta your cast it is not successful so you are getting the default value you have chosen with the nil coalescing operator. Are you sure didSet method is getting called?

Comment: Yes the didSet is called, I've added the print statement in the didSet which correctly fires with the time in the Picker's UI. ^^If you see I've added the print logs there from the didSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with how you store and annotate your view model. You should never be creating an `@ObservedObject` in the `View` itself, but rather injecting it. Whenever an `@ObservedObject`'s `@Published` property changes, the `View` which stores that object will be reloaded - this means that if you are initialising that `@ObservedObject` inside the `View`, a new instance of that object will be created.

You need to inject the object into your view to avoid recreating it every time your view is refreshed.

```
struct SettingsMain: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State private var showTimepickerEvening = false
...
```

And from wherever you create `SettingsMain` (let's call it `MainView` as an illustration), create `UserSettings` there and annotate it as `@State` (or if you are creating it from something other than a `View` - say a ViewModel, then make it `@Published`):

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var userSettings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
        SettingsMain(userSettings: userSettings)
    }
}
```

Comment: David, is it possible to instantiate a class like UserSetting() with @Published? 
I'm getting "'wrappedValue' is unavailable: @Published is only available on properties of classes" error from XCode.

Comment: @AditGupta my bad, that's because `MainView` is a `struct` and `struct`s cannot have `@Published` properties. If you're going to instantiate `UserSettings` in a `View`, make it a `@State`, if you're going to create it from another class (say a ViewModel), make it `@Published`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @DávidPásztor This seems to be working for me - thank you. But should it be a `@StateObject` instead of a `@State` variable? [This article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/state-vs-stateobject-vs-observedobject-vs-environmentobject-in-swiftui-81e2913d63f9) makes it seem like using a `@State` object wouldn't update based on all the individual `@Published` properties in UserSettings.

Comment: @Charlie if you're targeting iOS 14, then yes, `@StateObject` is more appropriate. However, `@StateObject` was not available at the time of writing my answer, since it was only introduced in iOS 14.