# Class Observable object @Published variable always empty

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to get the collection from firebase firestore. Below is my ViewModel I am unable to store the data in the @Published var categories object. I am unable to find the exact issue, I am a bit new to swift but the exact same thing was working a while back is there something I am doing wrong?

FormViewModel.swift

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class FormViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var categories = [Category]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchCategories() {
        db.collection("companies_by_category").addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = QuerySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }

            self.categories = documents.compactMap { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Category? in
                return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Category.self)
            }
            print(self.categories) // -> Able to get data
        }
    }
}
```

My CategoriesView

```
struct CategoriesView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewmodel = FormViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            List(self.viewmodel.categories) { category in
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                        //.foregroundColor(category.selected == true ? Color.yellow.opacity(0.5) : Color.white)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("\(category.category)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .font(.system(size: 20.0))
                            Text(category.category)
                                .font(.system(size: 20.0, weight: .medium))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.viewmodel.fetchCategories()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because you are doing an asynchronous call to your db so the print is executed before the data is returned. You should not be concerned with this since `categories` is published so any observer will be notified when the array gets values.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: Thanks I missed the fact that it was asynchronous, but as David explained in the answer the issue is not with the @ Published, but with the @ observed object as I am creating it in view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the fact that `addSnapshotListener` is an async function. Your second print will return no data, because it gets executed synchronously before the async network request of `addSnapshotListener` could return any data. You can only access the async data of `addSnapshotListener` inside the closure of the function.

However, the reason for your actual view not getting updated is different from the above. You are correctly updating the `categories` array from inside the async closure, so whenever the async request finishes, your `categories` will contain the correct data.

The UI issue is coming from the fact that you create your `@ ObservedObject` property inside your view. This is completely incorrect, since whenever an `@ObservedObject` property of a `View` updates, the view will be redrawn, which will result in its properties also being recalculated. You can fix this by injecting your viewmodel in the View's init. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63797060/saving-date-time-to-userdefaults-through-didset-on-published-var-from-timepick/63797546#63797546) for a more detailed explanation of how you should inject `@ObservedObject`s into `View`s.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, My view is still not showing even after initializing it in the main view as -
`
MainView - @State var formViewModel = FormViewModel()

CategoriesView(viewModel: self.formViewModel)
`

CategoriesView -

`
@ObserverdObject var viewmodel: FormViewModel
`

Comment: @RahulBajaj did you try debugging your code? Is `categories` actually updated and containing elements? If you put a breakpoint in the `body` of `CategoriesView`, does it get hit after `categories` was updated?